# Автоматически импортировать новый файл csv из папки с гугл диска в гугл таблицу

Tags: csv, google-spreadsheet, импорт

Я получаю раз в сутки, в гугл диск в папку в 0:02 мск новый csv файл с именем вида 08-5-21.csv, следующий 09-5-21.csv и тд.
Мне нужно чтобы этот файп преобразовался с заданными условиями при импорте: Не преобразовывать числа в текст и разделитель точка с запятой.
Далее нужно создать новый гугл лист с аналогичным именем.

importdada и importxml пока не могут мне помочь. coupler.io тоже, он обновляет данные одного csv
Как написать правильно скрипт подскажите боюсь мало в этом понимаю

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно написан standalone скрипт, который будет обращаться к глобальному классу driveApp, брать нужный файл, читать его и добавлять данные в новый лист указанной таблицы. После чего нужно настроить триггер на срабатывания раз в день в, например, 00:30.
Примеры кода для получения данных и добавления их в таблицу есть в примерах документации, Вам достаточно использовать их.